# Removes occurrences a given element within a list of lists

Tags: haskell

I have this function which removes occurrences of a given element within the list of lists.

```
remove          :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
remove    y []  = error "Can't remove an element from an empty list"
remove    y xs  = map (filter(/=y)) xs
```

How would I be able to do the same using List comprehension

Thank you

Comment: Why is `remove y []` an error, when e.g. `remove y [[]]` and `remove y [[y+1]]` are not errors?

Comment: Thanks dave I will add those erros Thanks :)

Comment: @Mike: you shouldn't make them errors. If you remove `y` from an empty list, it remains an empty list... the function should be total in this case, errors will only make it harder to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each `l` in `xs`, add `filter (/= xs) l` to the resulting list:

```
remove y xs = [filter (/= y) l | l <- xs]
```

or, removing filter by nesting comprehensions.
For each `xs` in `xss` and for each `x` in `xs`, keep `x` only if it's different from `y`:

```
remove y xss = [ [x| x <- xs, x /= y] | xs <- xss]
```

It's OK if you're just practicing , but your version with `map` is way better :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess something along the lines of:

```
 remove y ls = [f|l <- ls, let f = filter (/= y) l]
```

should be fine.

It basicly states that for every binding `l` you can make in the list `ls`, add the filtered list `f` to the resulting list.

Comment: Thank you that's great, can explain it briefly if it's not too much to ask.

Comment: @Mike: see Riccardo's answer, it's better : ]

Comment: @Mike: I added a short explanation